# I want to have a batch update like below in my codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
UPDATE forum_discussions SET category_id=70 WHERE category_id IN(1,2,3,4,5);

UPDATE forum_discussions SET category_id=71 WHERE category_id IN(6,7,8,9,10);

UPDATE forum_discussions SET category_id=72 WHERE category_id IN(11,12,13);
```

I want to write those 3 query in one batch query to update like $this->db->insert_bacth() in Codeigniter.

Is there any Idea??

I am trying in a way like bellow but can't see the success for CI.

```
UPDATE forum_discussions
    SET cetgory_id = CASE category_id
        WHEN 27 THEN 70
        WHEN 65 THEN 71
        WHEN 35 THEN 71
                                WHEN 31 THEN 72
                                WHEN 21 THEN 72
                                WHEN 23 THEN 72
                                WHEN 41 THEN 72
                                WHEN 42 THEN 72
                                WHEN 51 THEN 72
                                WHEN 63 THEN 72
                                WHEN 2 THEN 72
                                WHEN 3 THEN 73
                                WHEN 7 THEN 73
                                WHEN 15 THEN 73
                                WHEN 37 THEN 73
                                WHEN 11 THEN 73
                                WHEN 13 THEN 73
                                WHEN 17 THEN 73
                                WHEN 59 THEN 73
                                WHEN 69 THEN 73
                                WHEN 5 THEN 74
                                WHEN 29 THEN 74
                                WHEN 33 THEN 74
                                WHEN 61 THEN 74
                                WHEN 49 THEN 75
                                WHEN 67 THEN 75
                            END
                        WHERE category_id < 70
```

Comment: check error or try to keep code inside () after = and before WHERE

Comment: I hope update_batch() can only be used to update columns which are not in where condition.

Comment: Is the problem a typo? You have `SET cetgory_id =` should it be `SET category_id =`